# How could I make my app unshareable through shareIt app?

Tags: android, security, share

I am developing an android app and I want to know that,Is there any way through which my app will become unshareable from apps like shareit,etc?
Please tell me the way to secure my app.Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure an Android app against sharing apps like ShareIT & more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279857/how-to-secure-an-android-app-against-sharing-apps-like-shareit-more)